# How to adjust element width dynamically using jQuery or SCSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, sass

this is my first stackoverflow question, please be patient.

The problem is that, each time the browser is being resized, the image is overflowing on the text.

How can I fix the dashed element to be more responsive rather than manually adding some media queries? thank you!

```css
.romanweek-tablewrapper {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  display: table;
  width: 85%;
}
.romanweek-tablewrapper .menu-list-wrapper .romanweek-menulist {
  display: table;
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.romanweek-tablewrapper .menu-list-wrapper .romanweek-menulist li h4 {
  font: 400 16px Lato;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.romanweek-tablewrapper .menu-list-wrapper .romanweek-menulist li h4 .menu-schedule {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
.romanweek-tablewrapper .menu-list-wrapper .romanweek-menulist li h4 .menu-schedule::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px dashed rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  bottom: 5px;
  width: 95px;
  left: 7em;
  transition: 1s all ease;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1850px) {
  .romanweek-tablewrapper .menu-list-wrapper .romanweek-menulist li h4 .menu-schedule::after {
    width: 75px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1700px) {
  .romanweek-tablewrapper .menu-list-wrapper .romanweek-menulist li h4 .menu-schedule::after {
    width: 65px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1600px) {
  .romanweek-tablewrapper .menu-list-wrapper .romanweek-menulist li h4 .menu-schedule::after {
    width: 55px;
    left: 6em;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1400px) {
  .romanweek-tablewrapper .menu-list-wrapper .romanweek-menulist li h4 .menu-schedule::after {
    width: 35px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
  .romanweek-tablewrapper .menu-list-wrapper .romanweek-menulist li h4 .menu-schedule::after {
    width: 25px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .romanweek-tablewrapper .menu-list-wrapper .romanweek-menulist li h4 .menu-schedule::after {
    width: 15px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
  .romanweek-tablewrapper .menu-list-wrapper .romanweek-menulist li h4 .menu-schedule::after {
    width: 0;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .romanweek-tablewrapper .menu-list-wrapper .romanweek-menulist li h4 .menu-schedule::after {
    width: 250px;
  }
}
.romanweek-tablewrapper .menu-list-wrapper .romanweek-menulist li h4 .menu-item-description {
  float: right;
  text-align: left;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="romanweek-tablewrapper">
  <div class="table-header-wrapper">
    <h1 class="text-blue section-heading">Roman Week</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-list-wrapper">
    <ul class="romanweek-menulist">
      <li>
        <h4 class="menu-item"><span class="menu-schedule">Lunedi</span><span class="menu-item-description">We're closed<br> - You're cooking.</span></h4></li>
      <li>
        <h4 class="menu-item"><span class="menu-schedule">Martedi</span><span class="menu-item-description">Fettuccine</span></h4></li>
      <li>
        <h4 class="menu-item"><span class="menu-schedule">Mercoledi</span><span class="menu-item-description">Coniglio</span></h4></li>
      <li>
        <h4 class="menu-item"><span class="menu-schedule">Geovedi</span><span class="menu-item-description">Gnocchi</span></h4></li>
      <li>
        <h4 class="menu-item"><span class="menu-schedule">Venerdi</span><span class="menu-item-description">Baccala</span></h4></li>
      <li>
        <h4 class="menu-item"><span class="menu-schedule">Sabato</span><span class="menu-item-description">Vitello</span></h4></li>
      <li>
        <h4 class="menu-item"><span class="menu-schedule">Domenica</span><span class="menu-item-description">Lasagna</span></h4></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a link of the element
http://prntscr.com/gkwbcm

Comment: a code pen or something similar would be very helpful.

Comment: Instead of using px use % for width,   so your width will be relative to screen size.

Comment: Here is a sample codepen 
https://codepen.io/erishv/pen/JroJXQ

The dashed element is the thing i wanted to fix / make responsive

Comment: @Ashish451, using % on the width makes the dash not the same. 

See http://prntscr.com/gkwfxz

Comment: You are required to post your markup here, not codepen or any other third party site, which can change or disappear helping no one in the future: [mcve]

Comment: Okay, I will take your advice @Rob, thank you.

However can you help me with the question above?
How can I make the media queries minimize / reusable using jquery or SCSS?

Comment: It is not advice. It is a requirement. This question may be closed if you do not comply with this requirement.

Comment: Okay, there. Thank you for correcting @Rob :) 
Appreciate it.

Comment: Can you help me with the issue now? @Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<style class="cp-pen-styles">
    ul.romanweek-menulist {
        list-style: none;
    }
    ul.romanweek-menulist
     li .menu-schedule {
        width: 8%;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    span.menu-item-description {
        width: 20%;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }

    .dashed {
        content: '';
        width: 68%;
        display: inline-block;
        border-bottom: solid 1px dashed #333;
        border-bottom: 1px dashed rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    </style>    
    <div class="romanweek-tablewrapper">
            <div class="table-header-wrapper">
                <h1 class="text-blue section-heading">Roman Week</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-list-wrapper">
                <ul class="romanweek-menulist">
                    <li><h4 class="menu-item"><span class="menu-schedule">Lunedi</span><span class="dashed"></span><span class="menu-item-description">We're closed<br> - You're cooking.</span></h4></li>
                    <li><h4 class="menu-item"><span class="menu-schedule">Martedi</span><span class="dashed"></span><span class="menu-item-description">Fettuccine</span></h4></li>
                    <li><h4 class="menu-item"><span class="menu-schedule">Mercoledi</span><span class="dashed"></span><span class="menu-item-description">Coniglio</span></h4></li>
                    <li><h4 class="menu-item"><span class="menu-schedule">Geovedi</span><span class="dashed"></span><span class="menu-item-description">Gnocchi</span></h4></li>
                    <li><h4 class="menu-item"><span class="menu-schedule">Venerdi</span><span class="dashed"></span><span class="menu-item-description">Baccala</span></h4></li>
                    <li><h4 class="menu-item"><span class="menu-schedule">Sabato</span><span class="dashed"></span><span class="menu-item-description">Vitello</span></h4></li>
                    <li><h4 class="menu-item"><span class="menu-schedule">Domenica</span><span class="dashed"></span><span class="menu-item-description">Lasagna</span></h4></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks @yuiakino :)

Answer (score 0):

Use % on the height so that it can scale properly. Or if you need it to stop at a certain point use min and max width.